# Access a key in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am stuck trying to retrieve and modify the file below. I want to change the 'rating' from 0 to 5, however, I have no idea how to access the keyfile.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the `rating` value you can use `updateChildren()`:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("all_uploaded_image");
Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put("rating", 5);

mDatabase.child("-Luk55E0wNUE9bXk_pZ0").updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

> To simultaneously write to specific children of a node without overwriting other child nodes, use the updateChildren() method.

More info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is a real-time database, It has unique key to every child.

You can access/update them using those key.

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("all_uploaded_image");
mDatabase.child(KEY_OF_CHILD).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   //here you will get your child
                   //Now you can update it and again push it to same KEY
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```